# Image inspection before OCR preprocessing

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, ocr

We're running user-submitted images through OCR and sometimes our OCR application (third party) displays a warning about the image being too bright or too dark. I am considering writing a script to inspect the image before it goes to OCR and rejecting it if it's too bright or dark.

However, I don't have a clear understanding of what "brightness" actually means in this context. Is there some actual unit of brightness? Is it a contrast ratio? Something else? Are there optimal or "normal" ranges of values?

FYI working in Python-- would like to use PIL (or OpenCV, if necessary).

Comment: What OCR application are you using?

Comment: @JasonHarrison FlexiCapture. The brightness warning is generic.

Comment: @Tienkamp Not really an option for our workflow.

Comment: Given that FlexiCapture is a commercial product, and you're paying to use it, have you contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: Brightness in terms of OCR may refer to amount of contrast between text and paper pixels, for over-bright and low-light photos, OCR may not preform well.